# Is there a way to avoid using forceupdate in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a block of code like this:

```
    randomArray(arrayOfImage){
        //algorithm goes here
        return shuffledArray;
}

    shuffle(){       
        this.randomArray(images);
        this.forceUpdate();
} 

    render(){
        let array = this.randomArray(images);       //images is a declared array
        let squares = array.map((item,index) => <Squares/> )

        return(
            <div>
                <div id='square-container'>
                    {squares}
                </div>
                <button className='btn' onClick = {this.shuffle.bind(this)}>Shuffle</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Basically, I have an array `images` declared. The function `randomArray()` return a shuffled version of `images`. And then, for each of the item inside the shuffled array `array` the browser will render a div with the given props.

Now I have a button so that the user can shuffle the array themselves. Here, I use `forceupdate()` because even though the array is shuffled when the button is clicked, the DOM won't update because there is no changes in the state.

It works! But since using `forceupdate()` is not encouraged, how should I make this less... say, amateur?

Comment: Does it return a shuffled array, or does it shuffle the provided array in-place? Based on the usage in shuffle, it seems like the latter. Why not make the array part of the state, and actually *create a new one* to update the state with when shuffling?

Comment: Yeah, use local state, or some form of state library

Comment: So you are saying that I SHOULD use array as part of the state? I've always thought it's a bad way to code :D

Comment: It depends :) It doesn't mean that your data is static, you could have a load event that fills up the state (after which it would also re-render) or the data comes from props above but you are only interested in displaying / shuffling the array you have been given from a parent (so you might as well just shuffle indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, React will render an element again as soon as it's state gets changed, or it receives new props from it's parent component (or a state library).

You can read more about how react handles the rendering in [their documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation)

So, to handle this, just create a new array based on your original one, and then set it to the state again.

In the olden days, you would require a class for [setting the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) on component level

```js
const target = document.getElementById('container');

class ArrayOfImages extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    // don't forget to call super
    super();
    // set the initial state
    this.state = {
      images: [
      'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/18357/images/featured_story/Medium_WW252652.jpg?1576698319',
      'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/882/images/circle/African_Elephant_7.27.2012_hero_and_circle_HI_53941.jpg?1345532748',
      'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/1732/images/circle/Asian_Elephant_8.13.2012_Hero_And_Circle_HI_247511.jpg?1345551842'
      ]
    };
    // bind the function we are going to call from the render function
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind( this );
  }
  shuffle() {
    // create a shallow copy of the state object
    const copyOfState = this.state.images.slice();
    // shuffle it a bit (Durstenfeld shuffle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)
    for (let i = copyOfState.length; i--;) {
      let target = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i+1) );
      [copyOfState[i], copyOfState[target]] = [copyOfState[target], copyOfState[i]];
    }
    // update the existing state with the new array
    this.setState({ images: copyOfState });
  }
  render() {
    const { images } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Some elephants</h1>
        { images.map( img => <img key={ img } alt={ img } src={ img } /> ) }
        <div><button type="button" onClick={ this.shuffle }>Shuffle images</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <ArrayOfImages />, target );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

But now, you could do it by using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) helper for that

```js
// this would be an import in normal code
const { useState } = React;

const target = document.getElementById('container');

const shuffle = arr => {
  // create a shallow copy of the array
  const copy = arr.slice();
  // shuffle it a bit (Durstenfeld shuffle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)
  for (let i = copy.length; i--;) {
    let target = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i+1) );
    [copy[i], copy[target]] = [copy[target], copy[i]];
  }
  return copy;
}

const ArrayOfImages = () => {
  const [images, updateImages] = useState([
    'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/18357/images/featured_story/Medium_WW252652.jpg?1576698319',
    'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/882/images/circle/African_Elephant_7.27.2012_hero_and_circle_HI_53941.jpg?1345532748',
    'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/1732/images/circle/Asian_Elephant_8.13.2012_Hero_And_Circle_HI_247511.jpg?1345551842'
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Some elephants</h1>
      { images.map( img => <img key={ img } alt={ img } src={ img } /> ) }
      <div><button type="button" onClick={ () => updateImages( shuffle( images ) ) }>Shuffle images</button></div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <ArrayOfImages />, target );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The shuffle algorithm comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/3231537)